# Use ros launch to create a directory and then pass it's path to different nodes

Tags: c++, directory, ros, catkin

At runtime (when I call roslaunch), I want to create a new subdirectory in a known directory, and pass that path to two different nodes as a rosparam.

How can I edit my .launch file to do this?

For example,I have the folder `~/datacapture`. whenever I use roslaunch, I want to create a subdirectory based on the current time, (ie `~/datacacpture/20161129_1352/`) and pass that into a few nodes using rosparams.

To further explain what I want to do, here is an example roslaunch file:

```
<launch>
  <node
    name="node_A"
    pkg="pkg_A"
    type="A"
    output="screen"
  >   
    <param name="dataDumpFolder" value="???" /> 
  </node>

  <node
    name="node_B"
    pkg="pkg_B"
    type="B"
    output="screen"
  >
    <param name="dataDumpFolder" value="???" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

What i want it to look like is this:

```
<launch>
  #1) create a new folder using current date.
  #2) pass it's filepath into a variable. let's call the variable, NEW_FOLDER_FILE_PATH


  <node
    name="node_A"
    pkg="pkg_A"
    type="A"
    output="screen"
  >   
    <param name="dataDumpFolder" value="NEW_FOLDER_FILE_PATH" />    
  </node>

  <node
    name="node_B"
    pkg="pkg_B"
    type="B"
    output="screen"
  >
    <param name="dataDumpFolder" value="NEW_FOLDER_FILE_PATH" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Comment: It seems like a simpler way would be to write a shell script that creates the folder with an appropriate name, and then calls `roslaunch` on a [parametrized launch file](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in any generic way. It's also not a good idea as (a) roslaunch was not meant for this and (b) the error handling will be interesting.

If there is any way to not require a shared folder name, or if you could pre-determine it and pass it on to the launch file as argument, or if you could have a node that provides the filename (as service or via latched topic), this may be preferable.

That said, the best option to do this within roslaunch is to write a small shell script that creates the required folder and prints the name to stdout. This allows you to use `<param name="dataDumpFolder" command="your script" />`. You may need to remove some whitespace before using the value.